# How does BigQuery's FARM_FINGERPRINT represent a 64-bit *unsigned* int?

Tags: google-bigquery

BigQuery conveniently includes the `FARM_FINGERPRINT` function.  Here's an excerpt of the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#farm_fingerprint) for this function:

> **Description**
>
> Computes the fingerprint of the STRING or BYTES input using the Fingerprint64 function from the open-source FarmHash library. The output of this function for a particular input will never change.
>
> **Return type**
>
> INT64

Note that the return type is an INT64, which in bigquery is [a 64-bit signed int](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#integer-type).

However, if we look at [the actual implementation of Fingerprint64](https://github.com/google/farmhash/blob/master/src/farmhash.h#L151), we can see right in the header file that it returns an *unsigned* 64-bit int.

*The problem* A 64 bit unsigned int has twice the maximum value of a 64-bit signed int.  So half the time, FARM_FINGERPRINT will generate an output that is outside the representable range of a BigQuery INT64.  In such cases, what does BigQuery do?  Somehow it transform the output of `Fingerprint64` to fit into the range of a signed int, but the documentation doesn't say how.

One way to do this would just let the value overflow, causing the value to wrap around into the negative range of the signed int.  However, as `Fingerprint64` is meant to be a portable function, that seems like a poor design, because then its output in BigQuery differs from the standard output in other systems.  If this discrepancy exists, it should at least be documented with a big fat warning!

Comment: Playing around with the FARM_FINGERPRINT64, it looks like bigquery just lets the value overflow and 'wrap around' into the negative side of the integer range.

Comment: The documentation could say that there is a `static_cast` to a signed 64-bit integer.

Comment: The documentation says it uses "Fingerprint64 function from the open-source FarmHash library" but not that it's exactly that function. And since int64 in BigQuery is signed, it can't have the same values than uint64 (unsigned), so [Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) is applied in order to make them fit taking the first bit as the signed big. (Just as you explained, @ElliottBrossard and Conrad Lee)

Comment: I'll will provide your feedback about improving the documentation regarding this and I'll post my comment as community wiki :)

Answer (score 1):

The documentation says it uses "Fingerprint64 function from the open-source FarmHash library" but doesn't say that it's exactly the same function as it is. And since int64 in BigQuery is signed, it can't have the same values than uint64 (unsigned), so Two's complement is applied in order to make them fit taking the first bit as the signed bit. (Just as @ElliottBrossard and Conrad Lee found)

Comment: Are you saying that users should know this Fingerprint64 function differs from the open-source library, because it doesn't explicitly say it's exactly the same?  I don't think that's fair to users.  One of the main purposes of FarmHash (and MurmurHash before it) is to be consistent across systems, which is quite a useful property.  So I think that without some explicit warning, users won't expect this to be inconsistent with the open-source function on which its based.  A warning in the documentation will likely save BigQuery users some headaches!

Comment: I'm not saying this at all, I reported that documentation should be improved since it is unclear to me as well.