# Python vs BigQuery FarmHash Sometimes Do Not Equal

Tags: python-3.x, hash, google-bigquery

In BigQuery when i run

```
select farm_fingerprint('6823339101') as f
```

resuls in

```
-889610237538610470
```

In Python

```
#pip install pyfarmhash
import farmhash
print(farmhash.hash64('6823339101'))
```

results in

```
17557133836170941146
```

BigQuery & Python do agree on most inputs, but there are specific ones like the one above where there is a mismatch for the same input

```
'6823339101'
```

How can I get bigquery & python to agree 100% of the time?

Links to bigquery & python hash documentation

https://pypi.org/project/pyfarmhash/

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/hash_functions

Comment: damn it big-query is doing two's compliment on the output https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51892989/how-does-bigquerys-farm-fingerprint-represent-a-64-bit-unsigned-int

Comment: use MD5 is what i recommend to those using farm_fingerprint, that is exactly what I did

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned in the comments, the function is returning an `unsigned int`.
So we need to convert that as follows;

```
import numpy as np
np.uint64(farmhash.fingerprint64(x)).astype('int64')
```

Relevant issues: https://github.com/lovell/farmhash/issues/26#issuecomment-524581600

Results:

```
>>> import farmhash
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.uint64(farmhash.fingerprint64('6823339101')).astype('int64')
-889610237538610470
```

Comment: for common partitioning in bq:
`abs(MOD(FARM_FINGERPRINT(x), 3999))` the code is:
`abs(np.uint64(farmhash.fingerprint64(x)).astype('int64')) % 3999 )`

Answer (score 1):

Quickly scanning over the documentation that you have linked and `pyfarmhash` source:

The [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/hash_functions) for `farm_fingerprint` read:

> Computes the fingerprint of the STRING or BYTES input using the `Fingerprint64` function

But in your python code, you are using the `hash64` function, which according to the `pyfarmhash` [source code](https://github.com/veelion/python-farmhash/blob/master/src/python-farmhash.cc#L78) uses a different function from the `farmhash` library than [fingerprint does](https://github.com/veelion/python-farmhash/blob/master/src/python-farmhash.cc#L173)

**Solution**:

Use the same function `farm_fingerprint` is using

```
import farmhash
print(farmhash.fingerprint64('6823339101'))
```

Comment: farmhash.fingerprint64('6823339101') returns 17557133836170941146 instead of -889610237538610470

Comment: @MachineLearning the function is returning an `unsigned int`, you can convert that to a `signed int` using `c_int64(farmhash.hash64('6823339101'))`

Comment: Even with this fix, I don't get consistent results between pyfarmhash and BigQuery.